# collectionView didSlectRow bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, uicollectionview

Hello on a specific viewController of my project i have a UICollectionView with a custom class cell. But i have a big problem this that func :

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("tapped on a cell")
    }
```

when is click on a cell and instant realease (normal click) it does nothing, just nothing.

if i press and hold about 1s without release the finger it become grey, highlighted

And if i press and hold at least 3 seconds release the finger didSelectItemAt is executed correctly.
I tried to do the same on another project and that's work great but not on this VC and i really don't find the problem. The VC Bugged is of addTest clas in Main.storyboard

Comment: Please do not link to your whole code. Instead, figure out how to reproduce the issue in a minimal complete verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insight of Mojtaba Hosseini is very clever, but the answer given might not be quite correct.

It turns out that there is a UITapGestureRecognizer on the main view; if it recognizes before the tap on the cell, it prevents cell selection. But if you merely set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `false` on that gesture recognizer, then they *both* operate, and that seems unlikely to be what is wanted. We surely want the cell tap and *not* the tap gesture recognizer tap.

The correct solution is thus to give the tap gesture recognizer a delegate and implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`. Here, we look to see *where* the tap is. If it is within the bounds of a cell, we return `false`; otherwise we return `true`. We thus mediate between the cell tap and gesture recognizer tap.

Here is a possible implementation, demonstrated in a highly simplified form:

```
extension UIView {
    func isDescendant(of whattype:UIView.Type) -> Bool {
        var sup : UIView? = self.superview
        while sup != nil {
            if (whattype == type(of:sup!)) {
                return true
            }
            sup = sup!.superview
        }
        return false
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        t.delegate = self
    }

    @objc func tap(_:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("select")
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gr: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let v = gr.view {
            let loc = gr.location(in: v)
            if let v2 = v.hitTest(loc, with: nil) {
                return !v2.isDescendant(of: UICollectionViewCell.self)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

As you can see, we look to see whether the tap is inside a collection view cell; if it is, our gesture recognizer is prevented from recognizing, and the selection succeeds immediately.

Comment: Yes, matt it's more reliable **but** since I guess that `Gesture` probably handles only  **keyboard dismissal**, maybe this is not necessary and it's way more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a `UIGesture` or another interactable thing underneath the collection view. You should **DISABLE** its ability to `cancel touches in view` in **interface builder**:

[image: Attributes inspector]

or in code:

```
myTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: You're welcome. I knew what is the issue without the need to see your project but @matt is right! you should provide **minimal complete verifiable example** not the whole project. For this case, some information about the layers of the current view controller and the code of the class would be enough.

Comment: Very insightful and clever! However, now that you have so brilliantly identified the source of the problem, I don't think this is quite the right solution. I think what we want is a delegate on the gesture recognizer to prevent if from recognizing just in the case where the tap is in a cell.

Comment: Thanks but I think this is enough for someone that is not very familiar with iOS yet. and I guess that is a `UITapGesture` just for **keyboard dimissal**. (Common beginners issue.)